Unable to see the property dns_enabled in podman inspect network
I am learning the podman tool on Ubuntu sub system on my Windows machine.
Trying to know the dns status for the default network(podman) as well the custom one i have created.
But When i am executing the inspect command, dns status property is not displayed. Could you please any one help....
Listing the Networks
rvivekshiva@DESKTOP-I3BM780:~$ podman network ls
NETWORK ID    NAME        VERSION     PLUGINS
2f259bab93aa  podman      0.4.0       bridge,portmap,firewall,tuning
4c9a75cca717  my-app      0.4.0       bridge,portmap,firewall,tuning,dnsname
Inspecting the custom Network
rvivekshiva@DESKTOP-I3BM780:~$ podman network inspect my-app
[
{
"cniVersion": "0.4.0",
"name": "my-app",
"plugins": [
{
"bridge": "cni-podman1",
"hairpinMode": true,
"ipMasq": true,
"ipam": {
"ranges": [
[
{
"gateway": "10.89.0.1",
"subnet": "10.89.0.0/24"
}
]
],
"routes": [
{
"dst": "0.0.0.0/0"
}
],
"type": "host-local"
},
"isGateway": true,
"type": "bridge"
},
{
"capabilities": {
"portMappings": true
},
"type": "portmap"
},
{
"backend": "",
"type": "firewall"
},
{
"type": "tuning"
},
{
"capabilities": {
"aliases": true
},
"domainName": "dns.podman",
"type": "dnsname"
}
]
}
]
Inspecting default the Network
rvivekshiva@DESKTOP-I3BM780:~$ podman network inspect podman
[
{
"cniVersion": "0.4.0",
"name": "podman",
"plugins": [
{
"bridge": "cni-podman0",
"hairpinMode": true,
"ipMasq": true,
"ipam": {
"ranges": [
[
{
"gateway": "10.88.0.1",
"subnet": "10.88.0.0/16"
}
]
],
"routes": [
{
"dst": "0.0.0.0/0"
}
],
"type": "host-local"
},
"isGateway": true,
"type": "bridge"
},
{
"capabilities": {
"portMappings": true
},
"type": "portmap"
},
{
"type": "firewall"
},
{
"type": "tuning"
}
]
}
]

Which DNS provider are you using?

I had trouble getting the recommended aardvark-dns to work with WSL. Try this resolver instead:
sudo apt install golang-github-containernetworking-plugin-dnsname 

It seems, i am already having this.
golang-github-containernetworking-plugin-dnsname is already the newest version (1.3.1+ds1-2).
golang-github-containernetworking-plugin-dnsname set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

Have you deleted the network and started fresh with podman-compose up?
